# Is there any way to use a Service Worker with CEFSharp?

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to register a Service Worker in a javascript file executed inside a CEFSharp embbeded browser like this:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    console.log("Service Worker Supported")

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register("service_worker.js")
            .then(response => console.log("Service Worker: Registered"))
            .catch(error => console.log(`Service Worker: Error ${error}`));
    })
}
```

While debugging I can see that navigator does not have the "serviceWorker" property. Is there a way to add it? (Maybe by setting some CEFSharp setting or something similar?)

Thanks for you time!

Comment: Short answer: No.  It's simply not available in your particular JS environment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers

Comment: What version are you using? Exact version number please. Version `75` has the service worker object as expected when I look in DevTools. Far as I know plenty of people are using service workers.